# Dynamically how to add directives?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create dynamic directives. but i am getting error. any one correct me please?

here is my code :

```
var data = [{completed:40}, {completed:20}, {completed:55}, {completed:69}, {completed:71}]
var newApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

newApp
.controller('home', ['$scope', function ($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.data = data;
    for(var i=0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        $('.content').append($compile("<title></title>")(scope));
        $scope.$apply(); 
    }
}]);

newApp
.directive('title', function ($compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        replace : true,
        template : '<h2 class="que t3">QQQ</h2>',
        link : function () {
            console.log('link called');
        }
    }
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8vyduzam/1/)

Comment: Why are you doing that? Why don't you use an ng-repeat in the view? Generating HTML is the view's job, not the controller's job. http://jsfiddle.net/s9qb4v5p/

Comment: I am not able to get the solution for my requirement using `view` approach. that's why.

Comment: Just click on the jsfiddle link I gave you in my comment, and you'll have a solution.

Comment: I don't see any result in your page.

Comment: jsfiddle didn't save it apparently. Here is is: http://jsfiddle.net/s9qb4v5p/1/

Comment: Ok, I agree. But let me tell you my requirement. I need to add 4 no.of `h2` tag in `container` and each should have the percent in it. the last one 5 th data should be appended in to `h1` instead of `h2`. when `h2` clicked the h2 need to interchange with `h1' . i am trying here http://jsfiddle.net/8vyduzam/4/ can you give solution for this using view?

Comment: Sure: http://plnkr.co/edit/6P9rv8gQCbL9zxWzzNtT?p=preview Note how I don't overengineer things with useless directives.

Comment: Exactly I agree. can you make 2 template for each of them? (active with one template and reset with another template - to add additional stuff), this is very big kind of you.

Comment: What do you mean by "2 templates for each of them". The active item is in a h1, and the other ones are in a h2, so they already use 2 different templates. Of course, you can add whatever you want: CSS classes, additional text inside the h1 or h2, etc. That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, finally i have one question, how pass additional information from `h1` to span element, i used `{{name}}' but not update - http://plnkr.co/edit/UgeYXyPgkb9iz5OcXIM7?p=preview

Comment: `name` is a field of the item. So you must use {{ activeItem.name }} and not just {{ name }}, just as {{ activeItem.completed }} is used to show the completed field of the active item.

Answer (score 0):

Just missing a few things: http://jsfiddle.net/8vyduzam/2/

```
var data = [{completed:40}, {completed:20}, {completed:55}, {completed:69}, {completed:71}]
var newApp = angular.module('myApp', []);



newApp
.controller('home', ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.data = data;
    for(var i=0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        $('.content').append($compile("<title></title>")($scope));
    }
}]);

newApp
.directive('title', function ($compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        replace : true,
        template : '<h2 class="que t3">QQQ</h2>',
        link : function () {
            console.log('link called');
        }
    }
});
```

There were three things

- In the function, the second parameter accepts an array that lists all the services to inject into the last element of the array, the controller function. So you needed to add '$compile' so that it gets passed in.
- You were also using `scope` when actually compiling the `title` directive instead of `$scope`.
- During the controller function, it's already in a `$digest` loop, so you can also remove the extra `$apply()`.

Comment: Why i am getting a huge error consoled? error : `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply`

Comment: Yah, just noticed that and updated the answer. It was caused by the extra `$apply` call. Angular uses a digest loop that runs through and checks for any data changes and can only have a single run going at a time. The main controller creation function is already run in one, so you don't need to call it.

Comment: I am facing challenge to setting different percentage of each of my `directive` - can you help? http://jsfiddle.net/8vyduzam/5/

Comment: If that's all you're needing todo, Using `ng-repeat` like @jb-nizet suggests is definitely much cleaner. Dynamically compiling directives is useful/necessary at times, but there's often an easier approach.